# editing all attributes of jstree node

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Every time a node is selected for edit,

I open a new dialog with fields corrisonding to each node attributes.

I want to change the node's attributes.

Is it possible?

I know

```
 $("#jstree").jstree("rename", null);
```

will rename the node's name. But I want to edit all its attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to set new attributes to the nodes and then use [jsTree](https://www.jstree.com/) "refresh" method.